# "Required "app_id" key not supplied in config and could not find fallback environment variable "FACEBOOK_APP_ID""

Tags: laravel

Guys I am trying to create auto post in laravel using  laravel-notification-channels. But this is what shows

> "Required "app_id" key not supplied in config and could not find
>   fallback environment variable "FACEBOOK_APP_ID""

What can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to ad the config as explained here: https://github.com/laravel-notification-channels/facebook-poster#setting-up-the-facebook-poster-service.

If you have set the config and it still doesn't work, try: `php artisan config:clear`

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue, all I did was to wrap my `FACEBOOK_APP_ID` with double quotes:
`FACEBOOK_APP_ID="***************"`

Answer (score 0):

Please check `FACEBOOK_APP_ID` variable already in `.env` file with proper value.